# How to change intersection point of the axes and rotation point of the coordinate system?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a three-dimensional cartesian coordinate system (splot).

1. How can I set another intersection point of the axes?
   I want axes that intersect in the middle of my cloud of data points.
2. How can I set the point around which the coordinate system is to be rotated?
   By mouse wheel, I want to rotate the coordinate system and my data points around a center point that I have specified in my Gnuplot program.

Answer (score 1):

Rotated how?   Do you mean interacting with the display using the mouse?  Rotation is centered at the center of the field of view, not the origin of the axis coordinate system.

- mouse-wheel translates the origin along the x-axis
- shift-mouse-wheel translates the origin along the y-axis

There isn't a built-in hot-key or mouse button for translation along z, but I suppose you could define one using the "bind" command.